# connect to neo4jet from network not connected to the internet

Tags: c#, neo4j

I'm using a c# .NET MVC and I want to connect to a neo4jet database.

But `The Neo4j Driver is distributed exclusively via Nuget and can be added to your project via the Package Manager.` [[1]](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver)

How would I install the driver onto a network not connected to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**
You will need to download the Nuget Package from the internet on a different computer connected to the Internet.

You can download the package from

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4j.Driver/1.0.1
>   there should be a download button on the left which will allow you to save the file. (*note: this driver will only work with Neo4J 3.0 and Higher*)

**Step 2:**  Transfer the file to your development machine, via a USB flash drive or some other method.

**Step 3:** You will need to add the nuget package source to visual studio. 
Within visual studios

Click `Tools - > Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package sources -> Add (+)`

Add the name and source (location of the folder with the downloaded package) and update and OK.

**Step 4:** Right click on your solution and select **Manage NuGet packages for solution...**

Click on browse and select and install the Neo4j Driver to your project.
You should be able to start using the driver now.

Hope this helps.